# How to disable all checkboxes in a layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following code:

```
     <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/shifts_table_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tile_divider3"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

            <!-- Sunday shifts -->
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/table_row_sunday"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_sunday"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/volunteer_form_sunday"
                    android:theme="@style/textViewStyle" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_sunday_morning"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_sunday_morning"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_sunday_morning"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/volunteer_form_morning"
                        android:theme="@style/textViewStyle" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_sunday_evening"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_sunday_evening"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_sunday_evening"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/volunteer_form_evening"
                        android:theme="@style/textViewStyle" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <!-- Monday shifts -->
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/table_row_monday"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_monday"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/volunteer_form_monday"
                    android:theme="@style/textViewStyle" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_monday_morning"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_monday_morning"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_monday_morning"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/volunteer_form_morning"
                        android:theme="@style/textViewStyle" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_monday_evening"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_monday_evening"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_monday_evening"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/volunteer_form_evening"
                        android:theme="@style/textViewStyle" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <!-- Tuesday shifts -->
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/table_row_tuesday"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_tuesday"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/volunteer_form_tuesday"
                    android:theme="@style/textViewStyle" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_tuesday_morning"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_tuesday_morning"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_tuesday_morning"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/volunteer_form_morning"
                        android:theme="@style/textViewStyle" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_tuesday_evening"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_tuesday_evening"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_tuesday_evening"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/volunteer_form_evening"
                        android:theme="@style/textViewStyle" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <!-- Wednesday shifts -->
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/table_row_wednesday"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_wednesday"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/volunteer_form_wednesday"
                    android:theme="@style/textViewStyle" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_wednesday_morning"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_wednesday_morning"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_wednesday_morning"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/volunteer_form_morning"
                        android:theme="@style/textViewStyle" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_wednesday_evening"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_wednesday_evening"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_wednesday_evening"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/volunteer_form_evening"
                        android:theme="@style/textViewStyle" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <!-- Thursday shifts -->
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/table_row_thursday"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_thursday"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/volunteer_form_thursday"
                    android:theme="@style/textViewStyle" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_thursday_morning"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_thursday_morning"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_thursday_morning"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/volunteer_form_morning"
                        android:theme="@style/textViewStyle" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_thursday_evening"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkbox_thursday_evening"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_thursday_evening"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/volunteer_form_evening"
                        android:theme="@style/textViewStyle" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
```

I creates the following table:

[image]

When submitting the user's input I want to disable all button in the screen so he won't be able to click it. I could go through each one of the checkboxes and disable it but it feels like there is a better way to do it. I tried to disable the layout `shifts_table_layout` but it didn't work. How can I do it? Maybe should I change the table to some list? If so, how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a dummy solution for this as this layout are nested which go throw all items and disable it if it's a `CheckBox`

### **Solution 1**

```
fun setAllCheckboxStatus( layout:ViewGroup,enabled:Boolean){
    layout.children.forEach {view->
        if(view is TableRow){
            view.children.forEach {child->
                if(child is LinearLayout){
                    child.children.forEach {checkBox->
                        if(checkBox is CheckBox) {
                            checkBox.isEnabled = enabled
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then call it like

```
val layout=findViewById<TableLayout>(R.id.shifts_table_layout)
setAllCheckboxStatus(layout,false)
```

### **Solution 2**

put a any `view` Above your layout and make it clickable

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/shifts_table_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

        <!-- Sunday shifts -->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/table_row_sunday"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_sunday"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="volunteer_form_sunday"
                android:theme="@style/textViewStyle" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_sunday_morning"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox_sunday_morning"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_sunday_morning"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="volunteer_form_morning"
                    android:theme="@style/textViewStyle" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_sunday_evening"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox_sunday_evening"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_sunday_evening"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="volunteer_form_evening"
                    android:theme="@style/textViewStyle" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>
       ........
       .........
    </TableLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/shifts_table_layout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/shifts_table_layout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/shifts_table_layout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/shifts_table_layout"
        android:id="@+id/layoutAbove"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

then call it like

```
fun disableStatus(layout:ViewGroup,disable:Boolean){
layout.isClickable=disable
}
val layout=findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.layoutAbove)
disableStatus(layout,true)
```